# split text on multiple conditions

Tags: python-3.x, text

I would like to split strings of text based on multiple conditions.  I would like to take all text before the identified items. The individual titles may have MULTIPLE spaces between them, not just one as is indicated here and would like to be able to handle this as well.

There are two problems:

1. loop over multiple titles (not all indicated here)
2. which may have different amount of spaces between them

I have tried the following:

```
job_titles = ['senior payroll specialist', 'employment coordinator']

import re 
string = 'some text that has a bunch of words in it Blank Name senior payroll specialist 
with a bunch of words after this that are not needed'
out = re.split('senior payroll specialist', string)[0]
out = re.split('senior payroll specialist', out)[0]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider combining your split strings into one regular expression.  For example:

```
bash-3.2$ python3
Python 3.6.2 (default, Jul 17 2017, 16:44:32) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> job_titles = ['senior payroll specialist', 'employment coordinator']
>>> string = ('some text that has a bunch of words in it '
... 'Blank Name senior payroll specialist with the words '
... 'employment coordinator and words after this that are not needed')

>>> import re, pprint
>>> pat = "(" + "|".join(job_titles) + ")"
>>> pprint.pprint( re.split( pat, string ))
['some text that has a bunch of words in it Blank Name ',
 'senior payroll specialist',
 ' with the words ',
 'employment coordinator',
 ' and words after this that are not needed']
>>>
```

Comment: Ahh.  That does work. I ended up going with a for loop across all of the titles.  This looks like it will run a bit faster potentially.